# From Java byte[] -> Base64 -> Javascript ArrayBuffer -> Base64 -> Byte[]

Tags: javascript, java, audio

I'm having trouble sending data from Java to Javascript and the reverse of that.

Ive tried this so far:

```
//a function I found online I use it to convert the decoded version of the java base64 byte[] to an ArrayBuffer
    function str2ab(str) {
      var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
      var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
      for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i<strLen; i++) {
        bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      return buf;
    }

function ab2str(buf) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));//retuns a different value than what I put into the buffer.
}
```

I really don't know how to go about this anymore any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Java

using [`import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64;`](http://santuario.apache.org/Java/api/org/apache/xml/security/utils/Base64.html)

```
byte[] b = new byte[] { 12, 3, 4, 5, 12 , 34, 100 };
String encoded = Base64.encode(b);
```

produces:

```
"DAMEBQwiZA=="
```

## JavaScript

use [atob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob) and [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa)

```
var stringToByteArray = function(str) {
    var bytes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
        bytes.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    return bytes;
};
var decoded = stringToByteArray(atob("DAMEBQwiZA=="));
```

produces:

```
[ 12, 3, 4, 5, 12 , 34, 100 ]
```

*Note: If you are doing this in NodeJS then take a look at the [atob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/atob) package.*